# How do gold atoms formed in hypernova (or kilonova) explosions reunite?

Tags: atoms, supernova

It would seem that the force of the explosion, would disperse them over an extremely large area. How do they get reunited to one day be found clustered in flakes and nuggets?

I get that gravity eventually causes the cloud of matter to coalesce but it would seem that it would be as if all the elements had been thrown in a blender. Yet somehow the cloud of matter goes from a puree to a chunky stew. Are atoms inherently more attracted to their own kind?

Maybe my premise is wrong. Maybe the gold atoms survive the explosion in clusters rather than individual atoms wildly dispersed. But given then forces involved that doesn’t seem likely to me.

Comment: I think it's a phenomenon of geology... different kinds of minerals precipitate out of molten solution in different conditions, leading to concentrations of certain elements, including sometimes those sweet, sweet nuggets.

Comment: Also, on Earth, there are important biological processes involved in concentrating gold.